# Run the same code with different parameterizations on multiple nodes of a slurm cluster

Tags: fortran, cluster-computing, slurm

I have a fortran code with 3 scenarios.
I set a flag at the beginning of the code for which scenario I want to run.

```
integer :: scenario_no = 1 !Set 1, 2 or 3
```

I usually manually change this flag, compile the code, and run it into a cluster node.
Is there anyway to create a `sbatch` file to run each of the 3 scenarios on a different note without having to recompile each time?

Comment: See https://iric-solver-dev-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07/01_loading_args.html for how to read command line arguments into a Fortran program. This way your `scenario_no` variable can be set from the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the variable is hard-coded, you have to recompile every time you change it.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment, reading from a file may lead to problems when running in parallel. Better read from argument:

```
program test
  character :: arg
  integer :: scenario

  if(command_argument_count() >= 1) then
    call get_command_argument(1, arg)
    read(unit=arg, fmt=*, iostat=ios) scenario
    if(ios /= 0) then
      write(*,"('Invalid argument: ',a)") arg
      stop
    end if
    write(*,"('Running for scenario: ',i0)") scenario
  else
    write(*,"('Invalid argument')")
  end if

end program test
```

```
srun test.exe 1 &
srun test.exe 2 &
srun test.exe 3 &
wait
```

Make sure the outputs are done in different files, so they are not overwritten. You may also need to pin the tasks on different cores.

Comment: And this way lies race conditions.

Comment: Indeed, better from the argument. Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the post.

Comment: You can certainly read configuration from config files. But make sure that that different configurations are located and run from different directories. After all, you typically also want the output in different directories.

Comment: Yes, but the suggestion I have added was in a single file and changing it. That could give problems if the second change of the file was executed before the first job-run reach the reading part. In any case, I'd say the best approach to parallelize would be using MPI.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading in the command line arguments to the program.

```
integer :: clen, status, scenario_no
character(len=4) :: buffer
! Body of runcfdsim
scenario_no = 1
clen = command_argument_count()
if(clen>0) then
    call get_command_argument (1, buffer, clen, status)
    if(status==0) then
        read(buffer, '(BN,I4)') scenario_no
        if(scenario_no<1 .or. scenario_no>4) then
            scenario_no = 1
        end if
    end if
end if
```

This way you can call

```
runcfdsim 1
runcfdsim 2
runcfdsim 3
runcfdsim 4
```

and each run will have a different value for the `scenario_no` variable.

Comment: This way they'll run one after the other, and not in parallel.